# Spark 2.0.0 - JSON malformed output

Tags: javascript, json, scala, d3.js, apache-spark

I am processing data with Spark and Scala, and saving it in `json`

```
df2.write.mode("overwrite").json("mydata")
```

The output looks like this:

```
{"GPS_LAT":xx.xxxxx,"GPS_LONG":xx.xxxxx,"count":10063}
{"GPS_LAT":xx.xxxxx,"GPS_LONG":xx.xxxxx,"count":3142}
{"GPS_LAT":xx.xxxxx,"GPS_LONG":xx.xxxxx,"count":7766}
```

I use the data to create a visualization using `d3`, using `d3.json`:

```
d3.json("mydata.json", function(d){
                console.log(d)
};
```

My problem is that `d3.js` expects `json` to be formatted as follow:

```
[{"GPS_LAT":xx.xxxxx,"GPS_LONG":xx.xxxxx,"count":10063},
{"GPS_LAT":xx.xxxxx,"GPS_LONG":xx.xxxxx,"count":3142},
{"GPS_LAT":xx.xxxxx,"GPS_LONG":xx.xxxxx,"count":7766}]
```

Who is wrong? Spark or `d3`? What can I do to alleviate this situation without having to manually add `[,]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Spark, but I can say that this is not a valid JSON, you have just a bunch of objects that are not wrapped in an array. So, for *"who is wrong?"*, I'd say Spark.

But there is a (ugly) workaround. Use `d3.text` to load that *thing* (that bunch of objects):

```
d3.text("data.json", function(data){});
```

Then, your `data` will be a string. The next step is splitting the string by new lines:

```
data = data.match(/[^\r\n]+/g);
```

And, then, we transform this in an array of objects:

```
data = data.map(function(d){
    return JSON.parse(d)
});
```

All together:

```
d3.text("data.json", function(data){

    data = data.match(/[^\r\n]+/g);
    data = data.map(function(d){
        return JSON.parse(d)
    });
    //now you can use 'data' here

});
```

Check the console in this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/ER1oXyWZL62dwxlgaenP?p=preview

And, now that you have an array of objects, you can pass it to your D3 code.

**PS**: This may not work if you have dates in the data.

Comment: That's what I thought too - How can it be that a system like Spark produces a broken output?!

Comment: I can't say, as I told you, I never used Spark... let's wait to see someone else's opinion on this.

Comment: Because output is not JSON but [JSON Lines](http://jsonlines.org/) and this __expected__ result in Spark.

Answer (score 1):

We can also have a small `shell` script:

```
sed -i '' 's/}/},/g' file  # Add comma between each line
sed -i '' '$ s/.$/]/' file # Replace last comma with ]
sed -i '' '1s/^/[/' file   # Add [ at beginning of file
```

That does the treatment without having Javascript doing the leg work.